# Out of memory only on Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, memory-management

I just upgraded from a 1060-3gb to a 3070 TI, so I'm not sure if I haven't set it up properly, but everything runs perfect and smooth in the viewport without nearly maxing out my card, however, as soon as I render, it runs out of memory every time. It's not maxing my RAM either as it only reached 89%. I am not sure what is happening here and if it's because of bad render setting or if I improperly set up my GPU to run with Blender.

[image: scene]

[image: performances]

[image: blender system preferences]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change settings in Preferences-System. Example below is with different CPU, but shows options for changes[image]

Answer (score 0):

Optix rendering (RTX) doesn't handle the shared memory pool well and is causing some issue.  On very complex scenes it will be necessary to step down to rendering with CUDA on the GPU.

Hybrid rendering should work, but even if you choose only the GPU the CPU will still show some utilization.  Some tasks are offloaded to the CPU in all rendering scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issue while rendering but not in the viewport, my first suspicion would be towards your scene setup.

There are many things that are by default set up to be more intensive when rendering than in the viewport, a good example of that is the subsurf modifiers: by default it uses level 2 subdivision in the viewport and level 3 on render.

I'd suggest playing with the Simplify panel in the Properties Editor > Render tab. That might be one of the first things that might help.